# Find the Term of the sequence : $5,24,123,662,3121,...$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Problem :

Find the Term of the sequences $a_{n},b_{n},c_{n}$ :

$2,3,4,7,6,...$

$1,3,7,15,31,...$

$5,24,123,622,3121,...$

I need see simple  method to find term  for example second  term :

My try for second sequence :

Let : $b_{0}=1$ , $b_{1}=3$ , $b_{2}=7$ , $b_{3}=15$ 
We see : $b_{n}=2b_{n-1}+1$ then we will solve it by equation we get : $b_{n}=2^{n}-1$

I don't know if I'm correct or no 
Answer of one and three is : $a_{2n}=2n+2,a_{2n+1}=4n+3$ , $n≥0$ 
$c_{n}=5^{n}-n+1$ , $n>0$ 
And how I get other two term ??

Comment: your solution is correct for the second sequence

Comment: Yes sir @PeterForeman sorry , mistake type

Comment: No, it was $662$.

Comment: One way to spot the second sequence is to note that the ratios of consecutive terms approach 1/2: one has $3/1=2+1$, $7/3=2+1/3$, $15/7= 2+1/7$, $31/15=2+1/15$. This suggests the form $b_n=2^n A+B$, and by testing the first few cases we get $A=1,B=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The last sequence $5,24,123,662,3121,10100, 25319\ldots$ is given by
$$
a(n)=\frac{140}{3}n^4-\frac{1220}{3}n^3+\frac{3940}{3}n^2-\frac{5323}{3}n+826.
$$

Comment: How you get this ?

Comment: By finding a [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) for your values.

Comment: Surely this is not what was intended. It's impossible to know what exactly was intended, but I don't think this is a reasonable guess.

Comment: @MattSamuel I find it a good guess. I like polynomials, though. The page on the Lagrange polynomial also is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence $$ 1,3,7,15,31,..$$ is simply $$a_n = 2^n-1, (n\ge 1)$$

Your other sequence should have been $$5,24,123,622,3121,... $$

With the general term of $$  a_n = 5^n-n+1, (n\ge 1) $$

Comment: How you find the term I need method not by imaging ??

Comment: you can find the recursive formula $a_{n+1}=5a_n+4n-5$ and solve it as a difference equation.

Comment: Thanks sir @MohammadRiaz-Kermani

Comment: @EllenEllen  Thank you for your attention and understanding.s